# Deduct travel expenses for summer internship

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, rent, travel

I will be participating in a temporary (3-month) summer internship in a city that is quite far (over 300 miles) from where I study as a full-time student in graduate school. During the internship I will have to rent a temporary apartment, pay for general travel expenses (train, bus tickets, and food), and keep paying rent for my apartment in the city where I attend school.

My question is, am I eligible to deduct temporary living expenses **even though** I do not work while a full-time student in my home state? For example, can I deduct rent costs at the temporary job location?

I will be filing my taxes as an independent.

Comment: How on Earth are you going to justify being a "contractor" when doing an internship? That's such a blatant fraud...

Comment: You don't need to be a contractor to qualify for a temporary relocation tax deduction...

Comment: What did you mean by "filing my taxes as independent" then? And what is the "temporary relocation tax deduction" you're talking about?

Comment: I meant that I will not be filing as independent rather than dependent. I guess that was irrelevant.